# How do I increase number of workers in druid while using it through imply?

Tags: druid

I'm running druid through Imply's setup and I wanna increase the number of druid workers but I don't know exactly where should I change the configuration of Imply to increase the number of druid's workers. Can anybody please help me for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally I found the place where I can configure the number of workers for Druid in Imply's setup. Well, it was already documented in Druid's documentation but it was very vague to comprehend for newcomers.

Following is the location of the configuration file

> imply-directory/conf-quickstart/druid/middleManager/**runtime.properties**

We have to add new property called `druid.worker.capacity` which specifies number of workers for druid.

```
druid.worker.capacity=3
```

For instance above line instructs the Druid to run 3 workers of Druid